# Why doesn't the Node console display the function code?

Tags: node.js

In the Google Chrome console, if I type `fn` where `fn` is a function, then I get the code for `fn`. In the Node console, typing `require.resolve` simply prints out

```
[Function]
```

Why don't I get the function definition?

Comment: use `fn.toString()`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

From the comments: use `fn.toString()`.

Comment: I noticed, that when `fn` is defined in a lexical context, that string form doesn't contain any information about it, e.g. `function adder(n){ return function(m){ return n + m } }; a = adder(3); a.toString() => 'function(m){ return n + m }'`. Do you know any way around this limitation?

Comment: it is truncated. Is there a way to get the full function definition?

Comment: Since the function is printed with `\n` characters instead of actual newlines, it is sometimes advantageous to pass the toString() output into console.log, like this: `console.log(fn.toString())`